# How to pass nested Stack outputs to another step in Octopus Deploy

Tags: aws-cloudformation, octopus-deploy, octopus

In my Octopus project, the first step launches a bunch of nested stacks implemented with cloudformation.

I need to share the outputs of the master stack launched from Octopus, how can I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The output variables from the CloudFormation template will be available to later steps the same as any other Octopus output variable, this is mentioned in the first paragraph of the [documentation page](https://octopus.com/docs/deploying-applications/aws-deployments/cloudformation).

Output variables can be accessed a number of different ways, depending on where you are accessing them, for example, in Powershell they can be accessed via the parameters dictionary `$OctopusParameters["Octopus.Action[Step Name].Output.VariableName"]`.

You can also access them using the Variable Binding syntax, `#{Octopus.Action[Step Name].Output.VariableName}`

More information about output variables is available in the [docs](https://octopus.com/docs/deployment-process/variables/output-variables).

Comment: Apparently it doesn't work with nested stacks. I don't see the outputs of my master stack

Comment: I see only : Octopus.Action[CloudFormation].Output.AwsOutputs[StackId]

Comment: Octopus deploy doesn't wait the stack to complete and pass to the next step

Comment: The early exit issue was addressed in version 2018.3. See this [issue](https://github.com/OctopusDeploy/issues/issues/4345)